# How do I use the ETAS INCA Tool-API to log a comment during an INCA measurement using C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, calibration

I'm writing a C#/.NET application, using Visual Studio, that needs to trigger ETAS INCA to insert a comment in the log during a measurement. The C# application in turn is triggered by Arduino hardware but that seems to work well.

Currently the project is at a very basic state. I have included incacom.dll with the references. I believe I've pinpointed the method I need to use (namely `de.etas.cebra.toolAPI.Inca.IncaOnlineExperiment.WriteEventComment(string aComment, bool aFlag)`) but it's not straight forward how to use it. Here's the code:

```
...
using de.etas.cebra.toolAPI.Common;
using de.etas.cebra.toolAPI.Inca;
using de.etas.cebra.socket;
...
private void comment_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool flag = true;
            // I don't know what to do with this ToolClient.
            ToolClient tClient; 
            ClientSender cSender = new ClientSender(tClient);
            IncaOnlineExperiment incaExp = new IncaOnlineExperiment(cSender, flag);
            incaExp.WriteEventComment("Hello", flag);
        }
```

What I've learned so far is; WriteEventComment seems to require a new instance of IncaOnlineExperiment, which requires a ClientSender, which requires a ToolClient, which I don't know anything about. I guess this is incredibly basic but this is my adventure in these parts of the woods so please help me find my way.

Comment: Here's the trick--you shouldn't try to instantiate an IncaOnlineExperiment object using new().  Instead, you need to first connect to your INCA database, retrieve the workspace that has the experiment that you want to use, then open the experiment using a call on the workspace object.  I don't have the INCA documentation available at the moment, but you'll do something like "var myExperiment = myWorkspace.OpenExpiriment()".

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve it by doing what you said using 'Experiment onlineExp = Inca.GetOpenendExperiment()'. Etas support provided me with an example.